# aiohttp ClientSession.get() method failing silently - Python3.7

Tags: python, asynchronous, exception, python-asyncio, aiohttp

I'm making a small application that attempts to find company website URLs by searching for their names via Bing. It takes in a big list of company names, uses the Bing Search API to obtain the 1st URL, & saves those URLs back in the list.

I'm having a problem with `aiohttp`'s `ClientSession.get()` method, specifically, it fails silently & I can't figure out why.

Here's how I'm initializing the script. Keep an eye out for `worker.perform_mission()`:

```py
async def _execute(workers,*, loop=None):
    if not loop:
        loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
    [asyncio.ensure_future(i.perform_mission(verbose=True), loop=loop) for i in workers]

def main():
    filepth = 'c:\\SOME\\FILE\\PATH.xlsx'
    cache = pd.read_excel(filepth)

    # CHANGE THE NUMBER IN range(<here>) TO ADD MORE WORKERS.
    workers = (Worker(cache) for i in range(1))
    loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()

    loop.run_until_complete(_execute(workers, loop=loop))

    ...<MORE STUFF>...
```

The `worker.perform_mission()` method does the following (scroll to the bottom and look at `_split_up_request_like_they_do_in_the_docs()`):

```py
class Worker(object):
    def __init__(self, shared_cache):
        ...<MORE STUFF>...

    async def perform_mission(self, verbose=False):
        while not self.mission_complete:
            if not self.company_name:
                await self.find_company_name()
                if verbose:
                    print('Obtained Company Name')
            if self.company_name and not self.website:
                print('Company Name populated but no website found yet.')
                data = await self.call_bing() #<<<<< THIS IS SILENTLY FAILING.
                if self.website and ok_to_set_website(self.shared_cache, self):
                    await self.try_set_results(data)
                    self.mission_complete = True
                else:
                    print('{} worker failed at setting website.'.format(self.company_name))
                    pass
            else:
                print('{} worker failed at obtaining data from Bing.'.format(self.company_name))
                pass

    async def call_bing(self):
        async with aiohttp.ClientSession() as sesh:
            sesh.headers = self.headers
            sesh.params = self.params
            return await self._split_up_request_like_they_do_in_the_docs(sesh)

    async def _split_up_request_like_they_do_in_the_docs(self, session):
        print('_bing_request() successfully called.') #<<<THIS CATCHES
        async with session.get(self.search_url) as resp:
            print('Session.get() successfully called.') #<<<THIS DOES NOT.
            return await resp.json()
```

And finally my output is:

```sh
Obtained Company Name
Company Name populated but no website found yet.
_bing_request() successfully called.

Process finished with exit code 0
```

Can anyone help me figure out why `print('Session.get() successfully called.')`, isn't triggering?...or maybe help me ask this question better?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Take a look at this part:

```
async def _execute(workers,*, loop=None):
    # ...
    [asyncio.ensure_future(i.perform_mission(verbose=True), loop=loop) for i in workers]
```

You create a bunch of tasks, but you don't await these tasks are finished. It means `_execute` itself will be done right after tasks are created, long before these tasks are finished. And since you run event loop until `_execute` done, it will stop shortly after start.

To fix this, use [asyncio.gather](https://docs.python.org/3/library/asyncio-task.html#asyncio.gather) to wait multiple awaitables are finished:

```
async def _execute(workers,*, loop=None):
    # ...
    tasks = [asyncio.ensure_future(i.perform_mission(verbose=True), loop=loop) for i in workers]
    await asyncio.gather(*tasks)
```

Comment: Aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaand completely fixed...I should probably look into the different ways one loads an event loop.